# How do I create a puff / bump / bent effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

I am sorry for effect naming(!) but i couldn't decide the what is correct one for it, but you can see the example image below.

What is the most effective way to achieve this result with CS5?
Thanks.

Example Image

[image]

Comment: Which portion of the image? To me, it looks like 4 vector shapes with some gradient fills. The 3D rotation was probably done in Illustrator.

Comment: the part that i want to learn is bumping, it looks like there is a circle but it was raised from center a bit. And cut the upper part. I wish i can explain (sorry for amazing english :) )

Comment: There is nothing in my sense apply inner shadow, some gradient and drop shadow and some of wrapping to the direction you are done.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Fake" 3d effect in Photoshop/Illustrator with raster images](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/fake-3d-effect-in-photoshop-illustrator-with-raster-images)

Comment: It looks like there's a bevel because the center circle is offset and the ends of the ring, and the edges of the triangle are also angled accordingly. The only way to get this effect is to emulate a real 3D shape. Look at something with a similar bevel (a water bottle, a jar, a ball, etc.) and analyze its geometry and what are the visual indicators of the bevel (as opposed to a flat surface).

Comment: This is really a basic drawing or drafting question. Some elementary principles of perspective drawing would probably be the best place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy way to create this img would be to 
create a layer fill-it with black. apply white gradient   select out a oval. (save selection) select inverse cut it out.
cut out the center of the oval (save that selection too) and the top. 
create another layer on top of that one fill it with black. apply white gradient.  load the bigger oval selection adjust it a tiny bit so its a little bit smaller on the left. select inverse cut it out. load the small oval selection. adjust it so its a smidgin bigger on the right. cut it out. Select a giant circle half way trough the layer. select inverse cut it out. That should look like the top layer.

Creating the bottom most layer is the same process but its gradient is very slight. You can start with that layer if you wish and work your way up.

and then you need to create that little red triangle which is just cutting out 3 circles of different sizes from  a layer that's all red. (and is also not part of this question but just i case you want to copy this img layout i add it in)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to simply be an optical illusion created by the gradients used as well as a few curved lines on the arrow.