# Stacking Images Using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I'd like to arrange a few images like the following arrangement:
[image: Stacked images]

Could someone guide me on how to do this in Photoshop?

I am not sure whether it's related to *perspective* but I am not trying to achieve the look as in [this thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/8204/1854) i.e. the left side is shorter than the right side (and vice versa).

Comment: Original article: http://www.theverge.com/2013/1/24/3904134/google-redesign-how-larry-page-engineered-beautiful-revolution

Answer (score 4):

What you can use instead of Perspective is some skew on the right side (pardon my image, if you do it more carefully you will get a better result!):

[image]

What you do is paste your image in a new layer, go to `Edit > Transform > Skew`, grab the right side (not the top or bottom points, the middle of the whole side) and move it down a little.

Then, make the image narrower by using `Edit > Transform > Free Transform` (since it's in perspective, it's supposed to lose some width), or compress it like it's shown in [this question's first answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/perspective-manipulation) (I didn't do that in my image, sorry!).

Finally, bring the layer to 75% opacity or so and repeat the process for other images.

Comment: +1 on this solution. Make sure you take note of the values on the skew (in the options bar at the top of your screen), so you can repeat the process for all images and make them match perfectly.

Comment: Make an Action to apply the Free Transform/Skew Transform to your layers, this way you won't have to worry about typing in the values for each layer your transforming.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem, and if you have **Photoshop CS 6 Extended** is to use the **3D features**. I've provided ways to do this in the following a discussions:
["Fake" 3d effect in Photoshop/Illustrator with raster images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/fake-3d-effect-in-photoshop-illustrator-with-raster-images/8958#8958)

**This process is non-destructive** and you will retain all of the resolution of the original image(s).  Also, you can change your Camera to Isometric and then and you'll avoid any perspective issues.

I hope this helps.  Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you make the layer a smart object and skew that, then you can edit the contents of the object once you have skewed it.

Comment: This is more of a comment, so you should post it as such.