# Website Screenshot in Photoshop Perspective

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, perspective, portfolio

I'm web-developer and i decided to create my portfolio. So I need to create all my websites as images in perspective like on the following example.

[image: portfolio example]

I have knowledge of Photoshop, but I cant create what I need with good quality so please help.
If it is done in other software and not in Photoshop, please give me the name of that software.

I need not only the perspective angles, but i also want good quality of images.

Comment: this might also be relevant  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8202/how-to-slightly-rotate-my-photography-images-with-a-little-twist-of-3d-perspecti/8218#8218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Photoshop you might also have a CC subscription... in which case After Effects is the fastest way to do this, with adaptable and good quality, and true perspective, and the ability to instantly swap your entire portfolio in and out through the "template" you create.

After Effects uses a camera system for this kind of "3D". It's not real 3D, it's more like 2.5D, where you rotate the camera to best display the position of the planes upon which you place your images.

It is a little involved, but a quick watch of this video will give you a high level view of the problem of 3D in After Effects, and a great solution that should get you most of the way to what you want:

http://vimeo.com/45686886