# "Skewed"/Inclined 3D Style Tile

Tags: 3d, mockup, isometric

Does anyone have any idea how to create this realistic "skewed"/inclined 3D Style Tile?:

[image]

Things to note from this design:

1. The image "wraps" around the slab.
2. The image has a light source that helps create the realistic look to it. Look at how the lighting in the upper right side is lighter than the lower left side.
3. The location of the shadow is perfectly aligned with the tile.
4. The spread/blur of the shadow "fits" the distance of the slab from the surface.

I found [this old post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/fake-3d-effect-in-photoshop-illustrator-with-raster-images) from 2012, but the steps described by the author are to vague and can't enlarge his screenshots either.

I've been looking all over the web for a more helpful tutorial about how to accomplish this, but haven't been able to find anything.

Any help or pointers accomplishing this is GREATLY appreciated.

*Image taken from Jonathan Quintin's: [Weather Dashboard // Global Outlook UI/UX](https://www.behance.net/gallery/12748107/Weather-Dashboard-Global-Outlook-UIUX)*

**EDIT-9/25/14**

I was able to find the answer to my own question, but was unable to add it here. So I answered these two other very similar questions:

1. [“Fake” 3d effect in Photoshop/Illustrator with raster images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/fake-3d-effect-in-photoshop-illustrator-with-raster-images/39084#39084)
2. [How to achieve this 3D “Card” effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect/39083#39083)

Comment: I don't see what's so vague about the answers to the question you linked to. All the steps are there. I doubt you'll find an *exact*, *perfect*, tutorial specifically for your needs. You need to take the steps and translate them to your use.

Comment: This isn't really at all a hard effect to pull off. Anyway what do you mean by: "can't enlarge his screenshots either.". I mean its pretty self evident thet you can not magically create more resolution out of thin air.

Comment: Seriously we had this exact question all of 4 hours ago and voted to close it as duplicate. Unless you can come up with some specific question as to why the existing Q/As dont help you this isn't going to stay open.

Comment: In addition.... what software are you using????

Comment: Hey Ricardo, this is what's called Isometric 3D and here are a few tutorials on creating similar art in Adobe Illustrator:  http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/15-illustrator-tutorials-for-creating-isometric-illustrations--vector-5017

Comment: RE: Light and shadow, you can create these effects pretty simply in Photoshop.  For the shadow, you can make a copy of the shape, black it out, place on layer behind the original shape, and blur it. As to creating a light source, here's the official word on the subject:  https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/add-lighting-effects1.html

Comment: Only valuable answers by @Tom, a million Thanks brother. With your links I was able to find several free PSD files that use Smart Objects making the whole process incredibly simple. I had to place the answer to my own question in the actual question itself since the moderators here closed the forum. With your help Tom I was also able to answer two more forums that asked very similar questions. Thanks again.

Comment: @ricardozea you added the answer to the other question marked as duplicate there is no reason to include it in this one.

Comment: Glad to help @ricardozea.  Gotta love smart objects :)  Here's a great tutorial on making your own mockup templates:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZF0HnipaZ0

Comment: @Tom, Ha! Yes, that video is perfect for this question. Wish I could select your suggestions as answers, but... :p. Thanks again amigo.

Comment: De Nada, Ricardo :)

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a blanket answer: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)